# Why does injecting a script tag from a CDN JavaScript file use the origin host

Tags: javascript, css, http, same-origin-policy

If I load an external css from a CDN *(different host)* for example:

https://cdn.mydomain.com/css/styles.css

and then in `styles.css` do:

```
background: url('../img/bg.png')
```

`bg.png` loads from the CDN host *(https://cdn.mydomain.com/img/bg.png)* not the origin.

However if I do the same with an external JavaScript from a CDN *(https://cdn.mydomain.com/js/main.js)* and inject a script tag from `main.js`:

```
var a,b;
b = document.createElement("script");
b.src="/js/foobar.js";
b.type="text/javascript";
b.async=!0;
a = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
a.parentNode.insertBefore(b,a);
```

`foobar.js` is loaded from the origin, not the CDN host.

Why is this?

Comment: Because the src URL is *relative to the page* (the rules for CSS relative links are different).

Comment: Even if I change `b.src="/js/foobar.js"` to `b.src="js/foobar.js";` it still loads from the origin.

Comment: Because that is *still relative to the page*. Use `src="http://thecdn/thefile.js"`.

Comment: You're inserting the script tag into the head, the given URL is then relative to the page where it was inserted in, not the javascript file